# Taxation of gift from a foreign corporation owned by my parents?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, gift-tax

I am a U.S citizen. My parents who are not U.S. citizens have an offshore foreign company. If they send me a cash gift through their corporation:

1. Do I pay tax?
2. What is the max amount I can receive before I file form 3520?

Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully this has not *already happened* - if so, I think you're fucked. Best is just to send it back as if an accident.

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly sure a "corporation" can't send you a gift:

there is no such concept.

(The fact that "your parents" are principals in the corporation means nothing.)

Consider, I do a lot of jobs for Company X, one of my bigger clients.  (No, really - they're called "Company X"!  :)  )

Say they wired me 50 grand from their bank account.

And then they said - "Oh. That was a gift."

It's totally nonsensical.  It would just be a payment I'd pay tax on.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be grounded in facts.  Companies can make charitable contributions.

Comment: There is utterly no connection, at all, to a "charitable contribution" here. The downvote is very confused.

Comment: I didn't downvote and I'm not saying this gift is a charitable contribution. However you seem to imply companies cannot give gifts, but that is what a charitable contribution is.

Comment: @eric, "gifts" have utterly no connection, in any way, to "charitable contributions"